# Cortar uma imagem a cada 300 pixel de altura

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net

Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de relatório de Clipping onde preciso inserir imagens capturadas de paginas de internet. Na maioria das vezes é necessário corta-las e para distribui-las nas paginas do PDF. Como faço para cortar uma imagem programaticamente a cada 300 pixels de altura?

OBS.: Pode ser em VB ou C# a resposta.

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta o que você tentou, e seja menos abrangente no problema. Se não tiver tentado nada, o Google é um bom começo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um recorte no *bitmap* e depois fazer a conversão.

```c-sharp
public Bitmap CropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int cropX, int cropY, int cropWidth, int cropHeight){
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
    Bitmap cropped = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    return cropped;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, precisei apenas passar este metodo dentro de um loop FOR até o fim da imagem.